# Doxygenと外部ツールを連携したい

Tags: untagged

最近、C言語のフロチャートを自動生成するコマンドラインのツールを使い始めました。doxygenのcall graphと同じレベルでdoxygen出力にフロチャートをリンクできる方法が無いでしょうか？このツールはフォーマット指定をすることで関数単位のフロチャートをsvg出力します。

例えば、あるファイルのある関数のフロチャートをcall graphと同じように埋め込みhtml出力できればいいです。

フロチャート自動生成ツールyFlowGen
https://www.vector.co.jp/soft/winnt/prog/se517238.html
または、
https://github.com/toowaki/yFlowGen_jp/releases/tag/3.1.3

Comment: こんな記事があるようですので、プラグイン等で何とかする手法はあるようです。[Q&A：Doxygenで構造を記述して各種UML図・メッセージシーケンスチャート・フローチャート等を出力するには？](https://blog.cercopes-z.com/doxygen-diagrams-manual/), [how to generate flowchart from C code using doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51317890/9014308), [how to include flowchart into the doxygen html output](https://sourceforge.net/p/moritz/discussion/572218/thread/6fad0579/), [How Can Doxygen Help You Write Better Code in C/C++?](https://softacheck.com/how-can-doxygen-help-you-write-better-code-in-c-cpp/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になります。
Moritzというプラグインでも同じようなことが出来るのですね。
ただ、出力対象関数のソースに特別なコメントブロックをあらかじめ挿入しておく必要があるみたいです。
ソースコメントを編集する前提であれば、HTMLコマンドを挿入することでMoritzと同様にフロチャート図を挿入させることは出来るかと思います。もしくは、外部ドキュメントへのリンクですね。。。
ソースコメントを編集せずにどうにかしようと思うと、Doxygenの出力したHTMLファイルを関数名で検索置換するようなマクロを考えないといけないですか・・・。

Comment: t_kawaiさん
初めまして、作者のtoowakiです。
たまたま見かけたため書き込みました。 生成したフローチャートをdoxgenに追加できると便利ですね。yflowgenのユーザが増えるため私も興味があります。 doxgenにアドオンとして追加する方法などご存じでしたらアイディアいただけると助かります。